# A simple Google Chrome app to fetch details from a web form after each submission

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

There is this simple form that has two radio buttons, some text fields and a submit button.

Since, I have no access to the DB I want to make a Google Chrome extension that creates a DB/sheet from the browser that records/counts every form submission with a particular radio button clicked.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and supply some code.

Answer (score 1):

Well as i see your question is vague somehow, but from my understanding using a chrome extension:

1. you can inject a content script on the page that listens on the submission event  and update your counter following the radio button selected to submit the form (use jquery and selectors), the counter can be stored in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or in [Chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).
2. better thing you add the counter in the  background page by [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: De nada, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is good to solve very specific problems. Your post is not even a question. But I can tell you two things:

1. Maybe the browser extension is the wrong solution.
2. Yes, it is absolutely possible to write a chrome extension which listens to every (or a specific) website and to get the data from a form before it is sent to the server.

I also hope you don't want to do any harm with this technique. But the Chrome developers are checking every extension, that is uploaded to the Chrome Store, anyway.

If you started with your extension and need some help with specific code parts, you can come back and create a new question.